# How can I hide new files from all branches except the one it was created in?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

**Is there a configuration to prevent switching branches when there is uncommitted content in the present breanch?**

In my initialized GIT directory, I checkout a branch I call **libraries**. In there I download a number of javascript files. My intention is to clone the libraries branch into other branches so my javascript files are always present in the other branches. This works just fine.

My problem begins when I create new branches, **branch1** and **branch2**. Both contain the libraries directory but from that point my intention is for the new branches to contain entirely different files.

**The problem I'm encountering is when I create a new file in branch1 and then switch to branch2, I find my new file is present in both branch1 and branch2.**

I have tried to illustrate my issue below:

Starting with a cloned repository from GitHub, I have the following structure:

```
MyRepo
|_*master
  |__libraries
```

I create branch1 and branch2 with the following outcome

```
MyRepo
|_*master
| |__libraries
|
|_*branch1
| |__libraries
|
|_*branch2
  |__libraries
```

Now, I switch to branch2 and add a file, script.js. Without staging and committing, I switch to any of the other branches and I find my script.js file in all the branches.

I am familiar with staging and committing files in GIT but for my large projects, if I happen to add files to a particular branch and forget to stage and commit before switching to a different branch, I have files where they don't belong and I never intended.
I'm trying to preempt this by asking this question.

Comment: Do you have one repository for your library and one for you "project" or is this all in the same repository? If you merge "libraries" with "branch1" and "branch2" you should be able to have them contain different files

Comment: the file is not present in any of the branches until you commit it.

Comment: You should clarify the title of your question to what is the main problem that you're having, right now the title is very vague.

Comment: @turtlepick: It's all in the same repository

Comment: @bitoiu: I'm finding switching branches without committing a new file(s) makes it/them present in all the branches - not what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @sisko, the file seems to be in all branches because it is staged for commit, but unless it's committed it's not in any branch.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a **guess** based on your description:

When you are in a folder that has been git cloned (thus being monitored by git) and you add new files or modify existing files, and then you switch to another branch (using git checkout), these updates will be seen in other git branches. This is expected behavior in git.

If you want the updates to remain only in one branch then you will need to (git add and) git commit them to that branch. Until then they are present in your local folder even as you git checkout other branches. Which is the right behavior since you don't want the updates (that have not been saved yet with a commit) lost when you switch branches.

Based on your description, it is not clear what exactly you are doing. The actual sequence of git commands that you are using will help in providing a better answer.

Comment: Great, your updated description makes it clear. So I'm not sure there is a way for git to do what you are asking since git does not manage those files yet!

Answer (score 0):

Your file script.js is unknown to git, and so is not cleaned up when switching branch, as far as it is not in the new branch, so git  would try to overwrite it.

You never did a `git add` of this file, so for git it is non existent (untracked).
If you want to remove it you need to run another command after the switch, to clean files not tracked by git:

```
git clean -fx ./libraries
```

See git help clean for more details on cleaning a repository.